# When tapping a custom URL link in a UITextView the delegate receives nil URL

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, custom-url

I have a `tableView` with `tableViewCells` `cell` that show a `textView`.
`textView` uses an `attributedString` with custom URL link information, set up in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as shown in [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#textViewLinks):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedDisplayString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:displayString];
[attributedDisplayString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName 
                                value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username://%@", userName] 
                                range:NSMakeRange(0, userName.length)];
cell.textView.attributedText = attributedDisplayString;
```

When I tap the link, `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:` is called in the delegate, thus the custom URL link has been detected and responds.

However, **the supplied URL is `nil`**.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried setting the value as an NSURL (so you can guarantee that a valid URL is available)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried now to defined a URL using `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username://%@", userName]];` to set this as the value. But `url` is `nil`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't change the attributedText afterwards?  Can you add `NSLog(@"%@ %@", textView.attributedText, URL);` in your `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:` method?

Comment: So you need to look at why the URL is nil. If you supply a string that can't be converted to a URL you will get nil back (as you see)

Comment: You are right, I just answered my question before I could read your comment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for asking too fast. I found the problem, but maybe this helps others:

My variable `userName` simply contained a `space`, and could thus not be converted to a `URL`.

After removing the space, it works.

To make a string that can be used for a URL, one can use in iOS8 and earlier
`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`

and in iOS9

```
stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]
```